# How to make wpf combobox remember the previous selected value even if change it to new value?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mvvm, wpf-4.0

I want to display the default/selected value of the wpf combobox as bold even when the user selects the new value from combobox items. How to make the wpf combobox remember the previous selected value and make it bold so that the user can easily identify the previous value as it is bold.

Kindly help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how are the objects of your combobox created? I would add a boolean property called DefaultSelected to the class and then use datatemplate triggers in the combo box to style that one object with DefaultSelected = true.

```
      <DataTemplate x:Key="ComboTemplate" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock x:Name="myTextBlock" Text="{Binding ObjectName}" VerticalAlignment="Center"  />
            </StackPanel>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DefaultSelected}" Value="True" >
                    <DataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter TargetName="myTextBlock" 
                        Property="FontWeight" 
                        Value="Bold"/>
                    </DataTrigger.Setters>
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>


                <ComboBox 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding myList, Mode=OneTime}"
                          ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource ComboTemplate}">                        
                </ComboBox>
```

this is untested, sorry but should get you going in the right direction

J

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the reply. Got the direction and working fine. Thanks